# SharePoint: How to get list items by Content type id?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

I have a parent site and multiple sub sites. I need to access announcement list in sub sites by content ID as don't know there name in sub sites. I have tried to get the content id from this code:

```
web.AvailableContentTypes[SPBuiltInContentTypeId.Announcement].Id
```

But how do I retrieve lists from contenttypeid ?
I need some assistance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have achieved this via REST. The content type ID starts with 0x0104 of announcement type and when I retrieved the lists information via REST, the announcement type list has the BASE TEMPLATE of 104, so I filtered all announcement lists in a site via BaseTemplate.
Here is the URL:

```
http:site/_api/web/Lists?$filter=BaseTemplate eq (104)
```